# Format specifier %n not returning the count of characters

Tags: c, scanf, stdio, format-specifiers

First, I want to make clear that I'm a beginner and this might be a silly question and that I'm probably doing something wrong.

I want to read characters from a string until a `,` is found and store them in another string. I also want to know how many characters have been read. This is what I'm doing with `sscanf`:

```
sscanf(str, "%[^,]s %n ", newstr, &number);
```

When I try to print number it prints `0` regardless of my input, even when several characters were stored in `newstr`.

The problem seems to be in the `[^,]` sub-specifier as `%n` works as it should without it.

Comment: did you compile with warnings; what is the type of `number`?

Comment: I did compile with warnings. Number is an integer.

Comment: See [ask] and provide a [mcve].

Comment: remove the `s` from the format. It does not belong to `%[]`

Comment: I would proably just have written a bit of code to do it.

Comment: To expand on @AnttiHaapala's comment, the 's' character will not match the input stream at that point (the input stream will be a ',' character or EOF), so the `sscanf()` call will return at that point.  It should return 1 to  indicate that only one input item was assigned to. `number` should be left unchanged.

Comment: And of course the `s` is there just because you thought you're reading a **s**tring. But `%[^,]` reads a string already.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to read characters from a string until a ',' is found and store them in another string. I also want to know how many characters have been read.

The `s` is not needed.  It is not part of the `"%[^,]"` specifier.  Also the trailing `" "` serves no purpose.  Should limit input length too.  Do not use `newstr` unless code knows it was filled.

```
char str[100];
int number = 0;

// sscanf(str, "%[^,]s %n ", newstr, &number);
sscanf(str, "%99[^,], %n", newstr, &number);

if (number) Success();
else Fail();  // do not use newstr
```